# Keep all lines matching the highest value based on value in other column - Bash

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

Apologies; there should be an easy way to do what I want using a combination of `sort`/`unique`/`awk` but I cannot find it.

Here is a portion of the "clean" data table I've been able to obtain (sorted by column `Gene` and then `Length`).

```
Length  Gene                    
3013    ENSDARG00000000018      
3013    ENSDARG00000000018      
2933    ENSDARG00000000018      
2933    ENSDARG00000000018      
2933    ENSDARG00000000018      
2933    ENSDARG00000000018      
2033    ENSDARG00000000068      
2033    ENSDARG00000000068      
901     ENSDARG00000000068      
901     ENSDARG00000000068
```

I would need to keep **all lines** having the highest value in column `Length` for each `Gene` value. Here is the desired output:

```
  Length  Gene                    
  3013    ENSDARG00000000018      
  3013    ENSDARG00000000018      
  2033    ENSDARG00000000068      
  2033    ENSDARG00000000068
```

The solution given should work for a table with ca. 30,000 `Gene` values. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple `awk` should help you here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=(a[$2]>$1?a[$2]:$1);next} a[$2]==$1'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                              ##Checking condition here FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first time Input_file is being read.
  a[$2]=(a[$2]>$1?a[$2]:$1)           ##Creating an array named a whose index is $2 and value is depending upon condition if its value is greater than $1 then leave it as it is else replace its value with current $1 value.
  next                                ##next is awk out of box keyword which will skip all further statements.
}
a[$2]==$1                             ##This statement will be executed when 2nd time Input_file is being read and checking condition if value of a[$2] is equal to first field of current line, if yes then print that line.
'  Input_file Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name 2 times here.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
for gene in $(awk '{print $2}' myfile.txt | uniq); do
    grep "$(awk -v gene=$gene '$2 == gene {print $0}' myfile.txt | head -1)" myfile.txt
done
```